# Populating 2D char array leads to crash in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I am trying to populate a two dimensional array (mapLayout) with chars from a text file.

When I use printf to output the chars as they are being read everything looks fine, however the actual line that adds the char to the array seems to be causing a crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void createMap();

//height of file being read
int mapHeight, mapWidth = 20;
char mapLayout[20][20];

int main()
{
    createMap();
    return 0;
}

//read in string from file and populate mapLayout with chars
void createMap(){
    FILE *file = fopen("map.txt", "r");
    int col, row = 0;
    int c;

    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL; //could not open file

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        printf("\nx:%d, y:%d\n", col, row);

        if(c == '\n'){
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }else{
            mapLayout[col][row] = c;        //<--  This line seems to be the problem
            col++;
        }

    }

    return;
}
```

The file I am reading is a 20 x 20 representation of a map.  Here it is:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xA                 x
x                  x
x                  x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   x
x                  x
x                  x
x                  x
x                  x
x                  x
x    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x           x      x
x           x      x
x           x      x
x           x      x
x           x      x
x     xxxxxxx      x
x                  x
x                 Bx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are treating columns as rows in your code.

Comment: C fixed arrays are row-major. a[row][col].

Comment: Did you step through this with a debugger and check to see that `row` and `col` have the values you expected?

Comment: Well, there is `printf("\nx:%d, y:%d\n", col, row);` - I would image there is *some* output from it; what is it?

Comment: Your `CreateMap` is declared to return `void`, but returns `NULL`. It works correctly here, but has no error checking. And you should make sure each of the rows of the map is properly NUL terminated if you want to treat them as strings (the `map` variable is a global array, and C guarantees it will start filled with zeroes, but if you reuse it in any way, that doesn't help). Your rows are exactly 20 characters long, so you'd need space. You initialize `row`, but not `col`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int col, row = 0;` why `col` is not initialized to zero. If the first character in the file is `\n` then it will not crash, for all remaining cases crash will happen (undefined behaviour).

Do

```
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I clearly need to get more acquainted with C.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler, it could be that row and mapHeightd it not get anny value to begin with. 
try:
    int row=0, col=0;